# Global configuration Joomla after from xampp

Tags: joomla, configuration, xampp

I have a problem with global configuration on Joomla;

I've worked on local for my Web site and then I've uploaded it on remote;

it seems work perfectly but when I go to global configuration,

it opens a white tab with this error:

```
"Fatal error: Class 'JModelDatabase' not found in /web/htdocs/mydomain/home/components/com_config/model/cms.php on line 19"
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check that file database.php exists in /web/htdocs/mydomain/home/components/com_config/model/database.php

If it's not then you need to add it. But it is a sign that something wrong with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue i have come across before (and i work on joomla all day long), so the best thing to do in a scenario like this is do a fresh install of joomla core.

Go To **Components > Joomla! Update** click on **Check for Updates**, a new update will appear, click on **Reinstall Joomla core files**.

This will forcibly reinstall all core joomla files, presuming you have not edited any core files (which you should **NEVER** do), this should resolve the issue.

**EDIT**

**Reinstall Joomla core files**. will only display if you are already on the latest release, otherwise it will just be **Update** (or something)